# Cant echo anything after cURL in PHP

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

I have a curl that works fine. The file where the cURL is placed is a PHP file, executed by .ajax

I am echoing an `$apikey` at the end of the PHP file, without the cURL script. it prints correctly.

However, as soon as I put the cURL the `$apikey` stops printing the

```
$ch = curl_init("https://url");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
"Authorization: Bearer $apikey",
"Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8",
"Content-Length: " . strlen($data_string)
));

$json = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch); //close the connection

echo $apikey;
```

if I remove the `curl_init` line the `$apikey` is printed correctly.

I was thinking that somehow the cURL result was blocking anything executing after that, but realized that also `$json` is not printing if I try.

I have tried using also `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, false);` but no difference.
Couldn't find anything helpful here either.

Any idea of what might be the problem?

**UPDATE**
***The Ajax piece***

```
$.ajax({
 url: "curl.php",
 method: "POST",
 data: {
    date: date,
    time: time,
    account: account,
    userid: userid
 },
 success: function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    alert(response);    
 }
});
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227004/discussion-on-question-by-lstoilov-cant-echo-anything-after-curl-in-php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments / chat it would appear the root cause of the issue was that your AJAX call was never really working because a form was submitting at the same time and causing a page refresh. So removing this form submit will cause the button simply to fire the AJAX request and nothing else. Then everything works as intended. cURL is not at fault.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, ADyson. Just found out what the problem was... and funny enough it did not have to do anything with the .ajax, nor curl.... the button for triggering the ajax was within a form. So, submit was happening at the same time the ajax was executing. Removing the form tax fixed the issue.

But I believe that you deserve all the credit for getting to this point. So, please reply to the question so I can happily give you the points for it.